# Why there is no declarative immutability in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, multicore

Why the designers of C# did not allow for something like this?

```
public readonly class ImmutableThing
{
    ...
}
```

One of the most important ways to safe multi-threading is the use of immutable objects/classes, yet there is no way to declare a class as immutable. I know I can make it immutable by proper implementation but having this enforced by class declaration would make it so much easier and safer. Commenting a class as immutable is a "door prop" solution at best.

One look at a class declaration and you would instantly know it was immutable. If you had to modify someone else's code you would know a class does not allow changes by intent. I can only see advantages here but I can't believe no one thought about this before. So why is not supported?

**EDIT**

Some say this is not very important feature but that does not really convince me. Multicore processors showed up because increasing performance by frequency hit a wall. Supercomputers are heavily multiprocessor machines. Parallel processing is more and more important and is one of the main ways to improve performance. The support for multithreading and parallel processing in .NET is significant (various lock types, thread pool, tasks, async calls, concurrent collections, blocking collection, parallel foreach, PLINQ and so on) and it seems to me everything that helps you write parallel code more easily gives an edge. Even if it's non trivial to implement.

Comment: Because there's not.  Would be nice though, and would seem to open windows down the line if they want to enhance the language.

Comment: Isn't this what a `struct` is? (A class like entity with value semantics)

Comment: Here is a blog from Microsoft. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: No, structs are value types, a different kind of thing altogether.

Comment: @KirkWoll: You’re right; I forgot that the immutability of structs is a best practice (which most classes in the BCL follow), not a design requirement. I’ve removed my former comment.

Comment: I am not sure of any language with such as level of "declarative immutability". Even "more functional" (as in "less side-effecty") languages (e.g. SML/F#/Scheme and such) do not have the ability to express such constraints (AFAIK). It seems that it would generally be unverifiable *or* over-constricting past a very trivial definition. (Even a log causes side-effects.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, because it's complicated - and as usr wrote, features need a lot of work in various ways before they're ready to ship. (It's easy being an armchair language designer - I'm sure it's incredibly difficult to *really* do it, in a language with millions of developers with critical code bases which can't be broken by changes.)

It's tricky for a compiler to verify that a type is visibly-immutable without being overly restrictive in some cases. As an example, `String` is actually mutable within `mscorlib`, but the code of other types (e.g. `StringBuilder`) has been written very carefully to avoid the outside world ever seeing that mutability.

Eric Lippert has [written a lot on immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/immutability/) - it's a complex topic which would/will need a *lot* of work to turn into a practical language feature. It's also quite hard to retrofit onto a language *and framework* which didn't have it to start with. I'd love C# to at least make it *easier* to write immutable types, and I suspect the team has spent quite a while thinking about it - whether they'll ever be happy enough with their ideas to turn it into a production language feature is a different matter.

Comment: Why can't the an immutable type simply mean that every field must be declared readonly?  That doesn't seem too complicated or difficult, no?

Comment: @KirkWoll: A type which has a readonly `StringBuilder` member isn't as immutable as most people would want it to be. Basically, mutability is viral.

Comment: ah, I see.  I wasn't thinking it'd be deeply enforced.

Comment: I still think that declarative immutability should not be that hard. Probably I'm wrong but what about this: 1: all fields/properties are readonly/getters, 2: any publicly visible objects must implement and be exposed using `AsReadOnly()` or be immutable. It would involve quite some retrofitting but this happens anyway with new versions of .NET to some degree.

Comment: @MaciejDopieralski: It doesn't happen to *nearly* the degree required by this - and you'd also need to take account of situations where you wanted internal mutability but not external... otherwise `string` couldn't be declared immutable, for example.

Comment: Changing existing .NET classes to implement `AsReadOnly()` or be immutable is surely a lot of work. As for internal mutability it could be easily done by a class attributing just like `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` works for internals.

Answer (score 5):

Features need to be designed, implemented, tested, documented, deployed and supported. That's why we get the most important features first, and the less important ones late or never.

Your proposal is ok, but there is an easy workaround (as you said). Therefore it is not an "urgent" feature.

There is also a thing called **representational immutability** where state mutations inside the object are allowed but are never made visible to the outside. Example: a lazily-calculated field. This would not be possible under your proposal because the compiler could never prove the class to be immutable to the outside, although its field are routinely written to.

Comment: Not to mention that the problem is a lot harder than it might seem, and harder problems tend to get pushed back in favor of easier ones.

Comment: @MystereMan: I wouldn't say that, necessarily. There are lots of small, low-hanging fruit the C# team *could* have taken on instead of async - which is far from an "easy" problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet - That's why i said "Tend to".  There are of course exceptions when a problem is a) part of the marketing plan of a large number of products and b) really cool ;)